# What is the significance of calling a class method from an instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is it permitted to call a class method from an instance? How is it useful to do this?

Comment: It's not so much "is there a use case" as "is the behavior defined", and it is: a class method always receives a class as its first argument. When invoked from a class, that class is passed. When invoked from an instance, the type of that instance is passed.

Comment: If I invoke the class method with the instance, what would be passed in the cls argument of the method, the class or the instance?

Comment: The class will be passed. The instance is only used to look up the method. The `@classmethod` decorator ensures that the underlying function has the class passed to it; and it knows which class to use because of the lookup process.

Comment: See also: [How do I disallow a classmethod from being called on an instance?](/questions/42322936).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we use `@classmethod` to create an abstract factory:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, data):
        print(f'Making a {cls.__name__} instance from {data!r}.')
        a, b, *c = data.split()
        return cls(a, b, c)

class Derived(Base):
    pass
```

Testing it:

```
>>> d = Derived.from_string('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
Making a Derived instance from 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.
>>> d.c
['brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

By using an instance, we can create an instance that is known to be *of the same type* as the one we invoked:

```
>>> d2 = d.from_string('pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs')
Making a Derived instance from 'pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs'.
>>> assert(type(d2) is type(d)) # passes
```

Whether looked up directly in the class, or from an instance, `@classmethod` ensures that the class is passed as `cls`.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful when you have instances of different classes, and the classes have different implementations of the same class method. Calling `instance.method()` will call the implementation appropriate for that instance's class. You can think of it as a shortcut for

```
type(instance).method()
```

Example:

```
class Class1:
    @classmethod
    def method(cls):
        return "Class 1"

class Class2:
    @classmethod
    def method(cls):
        return "Class 2"

instance = Class1() if random.randint(1, 2) == 1 else Class2()
print(instance.method()) # Prints Class 1 or Class 2
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer with an explaination ?

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you've got a class that has six different methods on it. Five of them use `self` and do something complicated. But the sixth one just returns a constant, because it never changes based on the instance. It would be annoying if I had to remember to call

```
my_object.get_value()
my_object.frobnicate()
my_object.ping(100)
my_object.foobar(variable)
my_object.add(10)
type(my_object).version_id()
```

So, for consistency, it makes sense to be able to call that last one (which depends only on the class) on instances as well.